# Two dataframes, count repeated ids and merge with another dataframe with the same id?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, merge

I have two different dataframes, in the first one I have unique ids, in the second I have the same ids as the unique ones and they may appear more than once, some may not appear.

I want to do a count of how many times each id repeats in dataframe two, and after that merge with dataframe one into the corresponding ids.

### Dataframe 1:

```
id_unique  name
400        t1
450        t2
300        t10
600        t20
650        t30
```

### Dataframe 2:

```
id    other_columns
400   s1    
400   s2
650   s3
600   s4
600   s5
600   s6
```

### Desired result:

```
id_unique  name  count_df2
400        t1    2
450        t2    0
300        t10   0
600        t20   3
650        t30   1
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and replace missing values by `0`:

```
df1['count_df2'] = df1['id_unique'].map(df2['id'].value_counts()).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a basic example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'name': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2], 'name': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]})
df1['df2_count'] = df1['id'].map(df2.groupby('id').size())
```